# IIS returning 404 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: iis

I have a Windows 2012 server and have set up the folders appropriately in InetPub in the root directory.  I have created a .NET web application under Default Web Site but IIS is not returning any pages when I try to access the page with the address ExampleServer/Test.htm , I get 404 on WS2012 and on my local machine, any ideas why?

Comment: Do you see the default page when you access ExampleServer/ ?

Comment: I get nothing, when I do ExampleServer/ , I get a 404 error, when I do ExampleServer/iisstart.htm , I still get a 404 error.  When I have a default.htm, I still get a 404.

Comment: What does your IIS manager says? Are all the services running? Did you declare an URL to your application?

Comment: The 'IIS Admin Service' is running on Local System on the server.  What do you mean by 'delcare an Url to your application'? What information should I be looking for on IIS Manager.  I don't see any IIS related events in the event viewer.

Comment: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=793c0bc. If you select your app in the left menu and click 'Advanced settings...' in the right bar. What is its virtual path?

Comment: I don't have a place I can upload a picture and that site you uploaded to looks a personal site.

Comment: Application Pool:DefaultAppPool    
Physical Path:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project    
Physical Path Credentials:domain\a.user    
Physical Path Credentials Logon:ClearText    
Preload Enabled:False    
Virtual Path:/project    
Enabled Protocols:http    
    
Additionally    
    
DefaultAppPool    
Status:Started    
.NetFramework:v4.0    
Managed Pipeline:Classic    
Identity:ApplicationPoolIdentity    
Applications:2    

Every other option is default

Comment: Please excuse the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the "Default Web Site">Manage Website>Start

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue when deploying ASP.NET 2.0 to the server. Installing Windows component will resolve the issue.

- From Server Manager Dashboard/ Add Roles and Features
- Click Next until reach "Server Role"
- Expand Web Server (IIS) node
- Install all features in both Security and Application Development node, especially ASP.NET 3.5 feature.

Comment: I installed everything under Web Server (IIS) node .. still it's not working any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still having the same problem, but this ([getJSON Web API works on Development Server but IIS Express 7.5 throws 404 Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307824/getjson-web-api-works-on-development-server-but-iis-express-7-5-throws-404-not-f?answertab=active#tab-top)) worked for me.