# getJSON Web API works on Development Server but IIS Express 7.5 throws 404 Not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

Using Visual Studio 2012 and its ASP.NET Development Server everything seemed to be running well for my first forays into ASP.NET.  My Web API calls using jquery returned data.  In deploying to IIS Express 7.5 in order to start learning Authentication/Authorization I am running into a roadblock in my getJSON call:

```
GET http://localhost/api/OSList 404 (Not Found)
```

WebApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

getJSON

```
$.getJSON("/api/OSList", null)
    .success(
        function(data) {
            var mappedOs = $.map(data, function(item) {
                return new Os(item.ID, item.Name, item.PatchLevel);
            });
            self.OSs(mappedOs);
        }
    );
```

This all worked on Development Server... Is it something I have not set up correctly in IIS that would block this?

Edit: Added controller code, that was an obvious miss on my part.  This is default dev studio autogenerated.

```
public class OSListController : ApiController
{
    private readonly TrendDataEntities _db = new TrendDataEntities();

    // GET api/OSList
    public IEnumerable<OS> GetOS()
    {
        return _db.OS.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

And the HomeController uses:

```
public ActionResult OSList()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "OS List";
    ViewBag.Message = "";
    return View("~/Views/Home/Admin/OSList.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: What does your controller look like? We need to know what receives the requests that you're getting the 404 for.

Comment: @Jacob Added pertinent info as requested.

Comment: We were experiencing this when we had host names assigned in the bindings for all ports. We added an additional port 80 binding with no host name and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio Development Server runs your application on a specific port so that `http://localhost:<port>/api/OSList` will work. If you deploy your application to IIS, your application does not run on a dedicated port but 80 (by default) along with other apps. In that case, your URI must include your application name as well. So, if your application name is MyWebApi, then your URI must be `http://localhost/mywebapi/api/OSList`. getJSON must be something like `$.getJSON("/mywebapi/api/OSList", null)`.

Comment: Ahh!  nice.  That did work.  I looked into it further and found I had to change the project settings in Dev Studio to define `/mywebapi` as the Virtual Path and now I can make the scripting calls to both the same way.  Thanks a heap.